# Storing list in a pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, nltk

I am trying to do some text processing using NLTK and Pandas.

I have DataFrame with column 'text'. I want to add column 'text_tokenized' that will be stored as a nested list.

My code for tokenizing text is:

```
def sent_word_tokenize(text):
    text = unicode(text, errors='replace')
    sents = sent_tokenize(text)
    tokens = map(word_tokenize, sents)

    return tokens
```

Currently, I am trying to apply this function as following:

```
df['text_tokenized'] = df.apply(lambda row: sent_word_tokenize(row.text), axis=1)
```

Which gives me error:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (100, 3), indices imply (100, 21)
```

Not sure how to fix it and what is wrong here.

Comment: Hard to say for sure, but looks like axis=1 is a _row_ operation when you have a _column_ of text?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19667189/1168680

Comment: @user2241910, I do not think it is related to axis. You can still retrieve data from row by doing row.text. `df_small['text_tokenized'] = df_small.apply(lambda row: row.text, axis=1)` works well

Comment: @RAVI, I tried wrapping return statement in both tuple and list, but still have similar error: `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (100, 6), indices imply (100, 20)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my own question by using different axis:

Instead of:

```
df['text_tokenized'] = df.apply(lambda row: sent_word_tokenize(row.text), axis=1)
```

I used:

```
df['text_tokenized'] = df.text.apply(lambda text: sent_word_tokenize(text))
```

Although I am not sure why it works and I really appreciate if somebody could explain it to me.

Comment: When you specified `axis=1`, the apply function was operating column-wise(across **all the columns** of the dataframe). But you instead had to do the computation row-wise(across **each row** of the dataframe). Hence, the need to specify `axis=0`.