# Python, Pandas - ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 5), indices imply (5, 5)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to catch an empty list going into a pandas data frame but the above error occurs:

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 5), indices imply (5, 5)

I currently have a simple set up here:

```
if not daily_info:
    daily_info= ["No data found today","No data found today","No data found today","No data found today","No data found today"]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=daily_info, columns=['Send/Collect', 'Hospital', 'Courier', 'Kit', 'Manufacturer'])
    df = df.assign(Status="Not Started")
```

This may seem similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666904/pandas-dataframe-valueerror-shape-of-passed-values-is-x-indices-imply-x) where it is asking about appending an existing DF however the answers don't really help me with a different context.

Can anyone help me as to where i've gone wrong?

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50186267/21404794) by @rafaelc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need pass nested `list` to `DataFrame` constructor - `[daily_info]`:

```
daily_info= ["No data found today","No data found today","No data found today","No data found today","No data found today"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[daily_info], columns=['Send/Collect', 'Hospital', 'Courier', 'Kit', 'Manufacturer'])
df = df.assign(Status="Not Started")
print (df)
          Send/Collect             Hospital              Courier  \
0  No data found today  No data found today  No data found today   

                   Kit         Manufacturer       Status  
0  No data found today  No data found today  Not Started
```

Comment: It's bringing up this error now: "AssertionError: 5 columns passed, passed data had 4 columns" Despite the fact there's the right amount of amount of strings in the list - tried adding more out of miscounting and still says exactly the same with no numerical changes

Comment: @Colleen - You have to match number of values of list with number of values in list for columns names, if difference it raise error.

Comment: Nope I thought I missed something - your code works absolutely fine on its own however when adding it to the if statement the above error occurs @jezrael

Comment: @Colleen - Can you explain more? `if not daily_info` seems wrong, it is `True` or `False` ?

Comment: Sure @jezrael - it's simply a list that changes through the program. At that point it is empty, so False and that's when it's erroring

Comment: @Colleen - How working `if not len(daily_info) == 0:` ?

Comment: Or `if len(daily_info) != 0:`

Comment: the same occurs except the number changes in the error. With both those alternatives it is "AssertionError: 5 columns passed, passed data had 0 columns"

Comment: Use `if len(daily_info) == 5` because there is `5` columns before assign (it add 6.th column)

Comment: Do you mean extending the if statement as to be `if len(daily_info) == 5: (call pandas statement) else: (reassign daily info then call pandas)` because if that is the case the logic is flawed as the length of daily info changes whilst the columns stay constant (it becomes a nested list)

Comment: Yes, if `daily_info` is list solution working if matched number of columns with number of values in list `daily_info`, so `if len(daily_info) == 5:` is necessary.

Comment: daily_info is a nested list so i think the logic doesn't quite work there. Because we are checking for how many columns doesn't `try: len(daily_info[1]) == 5` work better logically? Because the length of the list changes

Comment: The problem with that is it still returns that old error @jezrael

Comment: @Colleen - So can you change `daily_info` with nested data? I think [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178453/discussion-between-colleen-and-jezrael).